# What needs to be replaced for correct eaves / roof edge?

Tags: roof, fascia

The last homeowner installed a patio roof - connecting support beams to the roof structure. It was a very flat roof -- that had lots of problems. 
I'd repaired it on multiple occasions - however, looking closer revealed underlying problems that could not be readily remedied.
In short, the patio cover is being removed (by me) and being replaced with a free standing patio cover (by a professional).

The patio professional has agreed to replace the fascia and soffits.

However, I need to fix some of the rotting roofing on the edge before he does this. I've done roof repair before - but nothing on the edge. I don't know what I don't know about getting the edges ready and fixed and what they need.

It looks as if the previous homeowner just removed the fascia board and nailed the patio rafters to the roof rafters. 
My thought is to simply remove patio beams he added, fix the roof decking, tar paper and shingles on the edge, and let the patio expert fix the fascia. What am I missing? what about eaves and the drip edge? Don't they need to be done before I can replace the roofing? 
[image: Missing Fascia and edges]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; let's see what our experts can come up with.